# C linked list insert function creating unwanted entry at the end

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am writing a simple C program and encountered a problem with my code. I am creating a circular linked list data structure and am filling it with data from a text file. Everything seems to work just fine, except that it puts an extra entry at the end of the linked list. Could anyone maybe point out what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution to this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
#define MAXLEN 100

//Definition of the structure:
struct list{
    char name[SIZE];
    int min, max;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
};

typedef struct list List;
typedef List *ListPtr;

//Function prototypes
ListPtr getData(ListPtr lst, ListPtr start);
void print(ListPtr start);
```

Here's my main():

```
int main()
{
    ListPtr lst, start;
    lst = (ListPtr) malloc(sizeof(List));
    lst->next = NULL;
    lst->prev = NULL;

    //Gets data from text file
    start = getData(lst, start); //Making start to point to the 1st entry
    print(start);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the getData():

```
ListPtr getData(ListPtr lst, ListPtr start){
    //For some reason aditional entry is created with system data in it
    char arr[MAXLEN];
    FILE *data = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    //while(fgets(arr, MAXLEN, data)){
        strcpy(lst->name, strtok(arr, " "));
        lst->min = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        lst->max = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        lst->next = (ListPtr)malloc(sizeof(List));
        lst->next->prev = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
    }
    fclose(data);
    start = lst; //start = end of the list
    while(lst->prev != NULL)
        lst = lst->prev; //goes to the start of the list
    start->next = lst;
    lst->prev = start;
    start = lst;
    return start;
}
```

And here's a function to check the entries of the list:

```
void print(ListPtr start){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        printf("%s %d %d\n", start->name, start->min, start->max);
        start = start->next;
    }
}
```

The sample of data.txt:

```
John 10 15
Mike 13 17
Anna 18 23
```

I want to create this list in circular fashion, so that later I could randomly select entries from it with generating a large number with rand(); and scroll through the list, as it gives the rand() more randomness. Any help with my problem is highly appreciated.

**Edit** Changing the line in `getData();` after `fclose(data)` to `start = lst->prev;` seems to have fixed the issue, but it doesn't seem right. Does this still create an unwanted entry and i just remove it from the list making it pollute the memory, or this is was just my logic mistake and it's the right way to fix it?

Comment: Every getData() does a malloc and there is an initial malloc in your main, so that's why there is the extra entry.

Comment: removing malloc from main() makes program instantly crash on startup, so i guess that's not the issue. Or should i put malloc somewhere else in the loop in getData()?

Comment: In the last iteration you create a new node with malloc, but you don't put anything in it! That's it!
This is why with lst->prev it worked

Comment: Yeah, it's a sketchy fix, but i guess it will do for now, since i'm not planning this little project to be memory hungry. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to keep the head of the list in a variable, let's call it *head*.
You can solve your problem with:

```
int getData(ListPtr *head, char *filename){
   ListPtr lst;
   int count = 0;
   char arr[MAXLEN];
   FILE *data = fopen(filename, "r");

   if (data == NULL)
      return -1;

   *head = (ListPtr)malloc(sizeof(List));
   lst = *head;
   while(fgets(arr, MAXLEN, data)){
       count++;
       strcpy(lst->name, strtok(arr, " "));
       lst->min = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
       lst->max = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
       if (!feof(data))
       {
           lst->next = (ListPtr)malloc(sizeof(List));
           lst->next->prev = lst;
           lst = lst->next;
       }
   }

   fclose(data);

   if (count == 0)
   {
       free(*head);
       return -1;
   }

   lst->next = *head;
   (*head)->prev = lst;

   return count;
}
```

So, in head you will have NULL in the case of empty file and the function returns -1 in case of errors. When the file exists and it is not empty it returns the number of elements in the list and head will be the pointer of the head of the list.

You should call this function with:

```
ListPtr head;
int nEl;

nEl = getData(&head, "data.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that misses an

```
lst->next = NULL
```

in the function getData() immediately after the while loop in which you read data from the file.

If you want a circular list you need to do this instead of what i've said above:

```
lst->next = <head of the list>
```

**Edit**
I've better read your code and you do the last thing that I've said you in this piece of code:

```
start = lst; //start = end of the list
while(lst->prev != NULL)
    lst = lst->prev; //goes to the start of the list
start->next = lst;
lst->prev = start;
start = lst;
```

The problem is:
In the last iteration you create a new node with malloc, but you don't put anything in it! This is why with lst->prev it worked.

Comment: yeah, im assigning the start of the list right after filling it with values. I suppose i should just assign it on creation in main, but i got lost thinking of ways to make it circular otherwise.

Comment: I advice you to free the memory before the termination of the program.  Maybe you can do it by storing the number of items in the list (you can count them in the getData function) and starting from a node you can free all the elements in the circular list. 
Each malloc should go together with a free.

Answer (score 0):

1) How your code is compiling ? lst is not declared in your print function. How your are accessing it in printf ? 
2) instead for loop use while loop with condition of start!=NULL

Comment: I just forgot to rename it correctly in print() while editing the code in the making of the topic. I'm using for loop to showcase the unwanted value, but the result with while loop is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

There are a few design problems with the solution; I would recommend a slight rethink and rewrite.

As Jim commented, the first is that you're creating an empty node before parsing the data. Suppose your data file is empty, will the list with its single node be valid then? Another design issue is that you're walking back through all the list nodes at the end of building the list, which is very odd and should not be required.

First, decide whether you would like to have a list *header*. This would be a different structure with pointers to the head and tail of the list and perhaps have a count of the nodes too, but not actually be a list node itself. That may be what you had in mind with the initial node that you created.

A header node is not essential though, and you could instead return NULL from your getData() function if no nodes were read, and you would create all of the list nodes inside that routine. The list header is nicer in some respects as it allows you to store list metadata and allows you to model and distinguish between an empty list (pointer to a list header with no nodes) and the absence of a list (null pointer).

A doubly linked list would go along the lines of the following. Write a createNode() function to construct a new node with data and next/prev NULL. The head and tail can be easily connected if you really need it to be circular.

```
ListNode* getData()
{
    ListNode* head = 0;
    ListNode* tail = 0;
    const char* data;
    while (data = moreData() /* wherever the data comes from */) {
        ListNode* node = createNode(data);

        if (!head) {
          head = node;
        }
        else
        {
          node->prev = tail;
          tail->next = node;
        }

        tail = node;
     }
     return head;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll definitely look into ways to optimize it. In this case i know how many entries the list should have, as I am filling the data file myself. Its just a code snippet from a simple text based game i'm working on in my free time from studies. This list holds heroes and their skill information, i just shortened it for the sake of readability.

Comment: "In this case i know how many entries the list should have" - *should* is the key word here, and what happens when the list doesn't :) Never assume things, because scenarios that should/can never happen *will* happen one day. In general that means coding error handling, but in this case, simply making the list robust. Move all creation to getData(), return either a list header or a pointer to the first node (and then 0 if the list is empty), and remove the loop that works backwards through the list.

Comment: I updated the answer with some sample pseudo code. You need to add a few supporting bits yourself.